# cakephp difference between Router::scope and Router::prefix

Tags: cakephp-3.0

i know that Router's prefix method adds a prefix to the routes but am still confused what the scope method does to routes.is it just an alias for prefix or has its own use.

```
Router::prefix('api', function ($routes) {       
 $routes->scope('/v1', function ($routes) {                       
 $routes->connect('/', ['action'=>'index']);              
 $routes->connect('/:id', ['action'=>'view', ':id']);         
}); 
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both allow sharing of common path segments. The difference is that a **prefix** will look for a controller within a sub-namespace.

from the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing):

> Prefixes are mapped to sub-namespaces in your application’s Controller
>   namespace ... Using our users example, accessing the URL
>   `/admin/users/edit/5` would call the `edit()` method of our
>   `src/Controller/Admin/UsersController.php` passing 5 as the first
>   parameter. The view file used would be
>   `src/Template/Admin/Users/edit.ctp`

In the above case, a **scope** would look for the controller at `src/Controller/UsersController.php`.

Comment: since controller and prefixes share namespace in the url pattern, how the does cakphp resolve that when doing routing?

Answer (score 1):

after some small research, i found out that **prefix** and **scope** are the same thing as **prefix** is just scoped route by definition.
routes scoping is a way of building routes so that common path segments and parameters are shared among scoped routes keeping your code DRY